# How can I change the onClick action of a ImageView dynamically?

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

I have a ImageView that does an action called setAsFavorite(). This action sets a product as favorite, so I change the image of the ImageView. But when the product is favorite, I want to change the onclick event, so when the user presses the imageView, the action called should be unsetAsFavorite() instead of setAsFavorite.
How can I change the onclick event dynamically?

Comment: Handle a boolean value on click event of imageview. Based on that, you can change the image of imageview.

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by av_lee is sufficient. But there is a better option.
Use `if` instead,

```
 boolean isFavourite = false;

    public void switchFavorite(){//Replace function setAsFavorite() with this
          if(isFavourite)
              isFavourite = false;
          else
              isFavourite = true;
    }
```

This way you decrease the number of function needed for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You could use A flag to know if it has been set as favorite then act on that

```
yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if(isSetAsFavorite){
                   unsetAsFavorite();
                 } else {setAsFavorite();}
            }
        });
```

where is isSetAsFavorite is of boolean type.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two operation in your `onclick` method `setAsFavorite()` & `unsetAsFavorite()`

```
int myFlag =0;

onclick(){

   if(myFlag == 0)
        setAsFavorite();
   else
        unsetAsFavorite();

}


void setAsFavorite(){

   myFlag = 1;

   //do your work...

}

void unsetAsFavorite(){

   myFlag = 0;

   //do your work...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to your ImageView:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.your_img_view_id)
```

and then assign a new listener to it like this:

```
yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // your code here
                }
            });
```

This way you change an old listener with the new one.